# How to shorter the code using each() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have a question. I have a script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {

        const windowHeight = $(window).height()
        const scrollValue = $(this).scrollTop();

        const $art1 = $('.art1');
        const art1FromTop = $art1.offset().top
        const art1Height = $art1.outerHeight()

        const $art2 = $('.art2');
        const art2FromTop = $art2.offset().top
        const art2Height = $art2.outerHeight()

        const $art3 = $('.art3');
        const art3FromTop = $art3.offset().top
        const art3Height = $art3.outerHeight()

        const $art4 = $('.art4');
        const art4FromTop = $art4.offset().top
        const art4Height = $art4.outerHeight()

        const $art5 = $('.art5');
        const art5FromTop = $art5.offset().top
        const art5Height = $art5.outerHeight()

        const $art6 = $('.art6');
        const art6FromTop = $art6.offset().top
        const art6Height = $art6.outerHeight()

        const $art7 = $('.art7');
        const art7FromTop = $art7.offset().top
        const art7Height = $art7.outerHeight()

        if (scrollValue > art1FromTop + art1Height / 2 - windowHeight) {
            $art1.addClass('active');
        }

        if (scrollValue > art2FromTop + art2Height / 2 - windowHeight) {
            $art2.addClass('active');
        }

        if (scrollValue > art3FromTop + art3Height / 2 - windowHeight) {
            $art3.addClass('active');
        }

        if (scrollValue > art4FromTop + art4Height / 2 - windowHeight) {
            $art4.addClass('active');
        }

        if (scrollValue > art5FromTop + art5Height / 2 - windowHeight) {
            $art5.addClass('active');
        }

        if (scrollValue > art6FromTop + art6Height / 2 - windowHeight) {
            $art6.addClass('active');
        }

        if (scrollValue > art7FromTop + art7Height / 2 - windowHeight) {
            $art7.addClass('active');
        }
    })
})
```

I would like to change it into shorter one using each(). I have in mind that I have to use $('.art') for example to select all divs with this class, then I need to add them numbers iterating from 1. This I think I can accomplish alone. But how can I calculate scrolling position for each div? How can I take the position of each div? Do I have to select it the way I am now, or I can use 'this' for it?

Comment: Put all the elements inside an array and loop over it.

Comment: Since you're treating all these elements the same way, is there any reason not to just give them all a common class?

Comment: SpoonMeiser not really, because they have to become visible on specific moment. If I made them all visible at the same moment, only first row would have animation effect on screen, rest will be invisible to human eye,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are performing the same operation use [Multiple Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and then use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) to get the matched element based on function used as a test for each element in the set. `this` is the current DOM element.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {

    const windowHeight = $(window).height()
    const scrollValue = $(this).scrollTop();

    var arts = $('.art1, .art2, ..., .art7'); //better $('.art')

    arts.filter(function(){
        const $art = $(this);
        const artFromTop = $art.offset().top
        const artHeight = $art.outerHeight()

        return scrollValue > artFromTop + artHeight / 2 - windowHeight;            
    }).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer : )